# Emacs CEDET Semantic no autocomplete for `this` keyword. (C++)

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeStructure
{
  int mMemberOne;
  float mMemberTwo;

  char MemberFunction()
    {
      int test = 0;
      ++test;
      this->  
    }
};

  int main()
  {
    SomeStructure abc;
    abc.MemberFunctionMemberFunction
  }
```

Any other autocompletion works in this file except when I'm trying to autocomplete `this->`. I get no suggestions. Running `semantic-analyze-debug-assist` gives me this:

> ```
> Unable to find symbol this.
>
> The prefix lookup code threw the following error:
>   (error "Cannot find definition for \"this\"")
>
> To debug this error you can do this:
>   M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET   [ Do It ]
> and then re-run the debug analyzer.
> ```

`M-x bovinate` gives me:

```
(("iostream" include   (:system-flag t)   (unlink-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays)    secondary-overlays    (#<overlay from 1 to 20 in junk.cpp>)    dependency-file "c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include/iostream" link-hook    (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays)    unlink-copy-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays)    :filename "d:/project/client/junk.cpp")   #<overlay from 1 to 20 in junk.cpp>)  ("SomeStructure" type   (:members    (("mMemberOne" variable
     (:type "int")
     (reparse-symbol classsubparts)
     #<overlay from 46 to 61 in junk.cpp>)
    ("mMemberTwo" variable
     (:type "float")
     (reparse-symbol classsubparts)
     #<overlay from 64 to 81 in junk.cpp>)
    ("MemberFunction" function
     (:type "char")
     (unlink-copy-hook
      (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays)
      link-hook
      (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays)
      reparse-symbol classsubparts secondary-overlays
      (#<overlay from 85 to 107 in junk.cpp>)
      unlink-hook
      (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays))
     #<overlay from 85 to 165 in junk.cpp>))    :type "class")   (unlink-copy-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays)    link-hook    (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays)    secondary-overlays    (#<overlay from 22 to 42 in junk.cpp>)    unlink-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays))   #<overlay from 22 to 168 in junk.cpp>)  ("main" function   (:type "int")   (unlink-copy-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-copy-secondary-overlays)    link-hook    (semantic--tag-link-secondary-overlays)    secondary-overlays    (#<overlay from 172 to 183 in junk.cpp>)    unlink-hook    (semantic--tag-unlink-secondary-overlays))   #<overlay from 172 to 250 in junk.cpp>))
```

So it looks like the `SomeStructure` structure is parsed correctly. It just looks like semantic has some kind of problem with `this`.

Also I followed the error's suggestion of re-running with `toggle-debug-on-error` enabled, however even with that enabled the debugger doesn't appear to break on error.

Using the latest version of emacs (24) and cedet (trunk).

I can't believe I'm the only one having this problem, it must be something I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corresponded with one of the maintainers (David Engster), and he was very responsive to provide a fix for this. The fix can be found in the CEDET's bzr repository as of revision 8490